# How can I print 2D arrays with four columns

Tags: c++, arrays

I am struggling with printing an array with 4 rows and 4 columns, when I initialized the array and entered all the values. Then,  I used for loop to get all the values together so I can print them. But I get is an array that companied all the values in one row.

I have attached the output when I run the code.

Here is a portion of my code, it is long code but I am struggling in specific part:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "The martix before I flipped it: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    

    int array[4][4] = { 16,3,2,13,5,10,11,8,9,6,7,12,4,5,14,1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard output utility `std::cout` is a stream from the stl and, as such, its << operator does not usually automagically append a linebreak.

Which is quite practical since, otherwise, you would not be able to print multiple numbers on a single line.

That being, said, you'll need to add the linebreak manually, like so :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can consider printing lines 4 at a time since your matrix is of constant size :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::cout << array[i][0] << " "
              << array[i][1] << " "
              << array[i][2] << " "
              << array[i][3] << " " << std::endl;
}
```

Have a great day,